# Does IronPython support multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ironpython, python-multiprocessing

Using IronPython 2.7 (`IronPython 2.7 2.7.5.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.42000`), I have a script which includes `from multiprocessing import Pool`. Trying to run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_compressed.concurrent.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "find_compressed.concurrent.py", line 59, in main
  File "IronPython 2.7\Lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 236, in Pool
  File "IronPython 2.7\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "IronPython 2.7\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 207, in _setup_queues
  File "IronPython 2.7\Lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 46, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing
```

Is it possible to use the `multiprocessing` module in IronPython? If not, is there another way to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this e-mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2011-March/014584.html) there is no support of Multiprocessing in IronPython.

But such module was created to workaround the GIL in Python, and IronPython don't have one, so maybe there are other ways, [this other e-mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2011-March/014603.html) suggests using .NET's [`ThreadPools`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Comment: Yes, depending on what should be achieved [AsParallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413602(v=vs.100).aspx) and LINQ work quite well in IronPython